# With library Cheerio.js I'd like to replace the content with a some string rather than leaving it

Tags: cheerio

I've written a content scraper code with library Cheerio.js, it read the content of a webpage and grabs me some values like location name, street address, and phone no.

In some places, the street address isn't provided so it skips that place which isn't cool.

Here is an example of the webpage that I'm getting the data from.

https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Medical%20Ambulance&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=2

How do I detect if the street address isn't located here & my code should replace the empty content with something else?

Full code is located here.
https://github.com/jpca999/yellowpageScrapper/blob/master/indexWithAsyncArray.js

Currently, in the output, it just skips the empty street names.

```
const getStreetAddress = async () => {
  console.log(' calling getStreetAddress'); 
  const html = await rp(baseURL + searchURL);
  const businessMap = cheerio('div.street-address', html).map(async (i, e) => {

    
    const streetAddress = e.children[0].parent.children[0].data;
 console.log('Here it shold detect if the variable "streetAddress"  has some value then leave it or else replace the value with something' );
 
    return {
      streetAddress,
    }

  })
  .get();
  return Promise.all(businessMap);
};
```

Here's the output.

[image]

Comment: I can tell you right now, you'll get better results if you take the relevant code and put it in the question instead of linking to a GitHub.

Comment: @corsiKa   Added code above here.

Answer (score 0):

If this were mine, and unfortunately I have no way to test this myself with your entire code base, I would just check the value against a default value. The basic paradigm I've used in JavaScript, which some people like and some don't, and you can adapt to your own taste, is

```
const actualValue = possibleValue || defaultValue;
```

So in your case it might be

```
const streetAddress = e.children[0].parent.children[0].data || 'No Street Address Provided';
```

This is because null, undefined, and empty string are all falsey value and such will cause the default value to be assigned.

You can do the same thing after your object is returned, for example

```
const businessMap = ... blah ... .get();
businessMap.streetAddress = businessMap.streetAddress || 'No Street Address Provided';
return Promise.all(businessMap);
```

Comment: Not working, it stays the same. You can try running that file, after doing npm install.  It doesn't require too much setup.

Comment: It's entirely possible your HTML provided just doesn't have that div so it never fires. I'll add another thing you can try, but I can't commit to actually installing anything. I don't even have a node environment set up on this computer lol

Comment: @JP. Added an alternative example of using default values, this time outside of your async.

Comment: I don't think those bitwise ORs (`|`) are what you think they are.

Comment: @pguardiario Lol I knew something was up - although I can say the code I put in there worked because, well, JS interprets things weirdly.... but you're right, logical is much better.

Comment: @pguardiario   I tried all the options. None of them worked. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That page doesn't load for me, but it should look something like (assuming the css for streetAddress is `.foo`)

```
const $ = cheerio.load(html)
const businessMap = $('div.street-address').get().map(div => {
  return {
    streetAddress: $(div).find('.foo').first().text() || "???"
  }
})
```

Also note that cheerio doesn't use promises because there's no IO.

Also note that the empty string "" is falsey in JS which is why this works.

Comment: It didn't work. & promises work becuase my code is working except this minor issue.

Comment: It won't work as is, you need to adjust the css for that element. I can't load the page so unless you post some HTML you're on your own. Also please take my word for it, you don't need promises.

Comment: I can’t adjust css of other pages, that’s out of my control.

Comment: Here is the code & it fetches HTML from a page on yellowpages.com.      https://github.com/jpca999/yellowpageScrapper/blob/master/indexWithAsyncArray.js

Comment: *sigh* I'm posting an example of what that would like if the streetAddress element were `.foo`. I can't see the html so I I can't suggest what the css for that might be.